# Передача данных из формы в mysql!

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите пожалуйста почему не работает.
Ошибка - Информация не занесена в базу данных

```js
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['href'])){

    // Переменные с формы
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $href = $_POST['href'];
    
    // Параметры для подключения
    $db_host = "localhost"; 
    $db_user = "root"; // Логин БД
    $db_password = ""; // Пароль БД
    $db_base = 'testbase'; // Имя БД
    $db_table = "products"; // Имя Таблицы БД
    
    // Подключение к базе данных
    $mysqli = new mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_base);

    // Если есть ошибка соединения, выводим её и убиваем подключение
 if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
     die('Ошибка : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
 }
    
    $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ".$db_table."(name,href) VALUES ('$name','$href')");
    print_r($_POST);
    if ($result == true){
     echo "Информация занесена в базу данных";
    }else{
     echo "Информация не занесена в базу данных";
    }
}
?>
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="up.php">
  <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Имя" />
  <input name="href" type="text" placeholder="Текст" />
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
</form>
```

Comment: Вы получаете какое-либо сообщение об ошибке или скрипт отрабатывает успешно? Если есть ошибка, то приведите её текст в вашем вопросе.

Comment: Информация не занесена в базу данных

Comment: else{
    echo "Oshibka".mysqli_error($mysqli);
  }  добавте и узнаете ошибку

Comment: скорее всего конкатенация ".$db_table." '$name','$href'  обычно я делаю так $query1 = "INSERT INTO tabl2 (oldname, newname, znachenie) VALUES ( '". $oldname."','".$name."','".$znach."')";

Comment: `query("INSERT INTO '.$db_table.' (name,href) VALUES ('$name','$href')");` попробуйте так

Comment: Сам код рабочий. Проверьте на наличии опечаток в названии таблиц и столбцов в базе данных.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно в phpmyadmin OpenServer нужно установить пароль пользователя БД. И в целом проверить есть ли подключение к БД